# PANDAS - I need the program to find some values, if the value is >= 4, then it returns the header of that column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, header, row, spreadsheet

Good evening.

I’m having a hard time with pandas.
The short explanation is that I need the program to find some values, if the value is >= 4, then it returns the header of that column.

With that simple explanation out of the way, I’ll give more details.
First of all, I’m still learning python, and I’m coding this while I get more knowledge.

This is for a correction program of a psychological diagnostic test.
All starts with a google form with 90 questions, and the patient has to choose a value from 1 to 6.
After, the form will become a google spreadsheet. The first 6 columns are questions about personal data, and the following 90 ones are the psychological diagnostic test.

[image: Spreadsheet example image]

So, the user will input the name of the patient, the program will find the row of the name and get all values from the 90 questions. Then it will group which one with its mental disorder and calculate the results. At the end, it will print the result, and the values for the user.

[image: Print results image]

Until here we are fine. I was able to write a code that does it just right. Not the finest, but works.

But, in some situations, the patient gives a high value for a question outside the mental disorder group, and for this, it's good that the psychologist take a look at those for a better analysis.
And that's where I’m struggling with. I don't know how to locate the values >=4 in a certain name roll, and then get the column name (header), that is the question.

Here are some parts of the code,with just one mental disorder (there are 18), so you can see how I got here:

```
# CÓDIGO CORREÇÃO YQS:#
 
worksheet = gc.open('Protótipo Teste YSQ - S3 (respostas)').sheet1
 
# get_all_values gives a list of rows.#
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
 
# Convert to a DataFrame and render.#
import pandas as pd
 
#Reseta and creates a new index per numbers.#
v1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
v2 = v1.reset_index()
v2 = v1.set_index(1)
 
#Gets the name input to find the name’s row.#
nome = str(input('Nome completo: '))
 
#Creates a new dataframe with the name, row and new columns with the results.#
v3 = (v2.loc[nome, 6:95])
v3['m1'] = (int(v3[6]) + int(v3[24]) + int(v3[42]) + int(v3[60]) + int(v3[78])) / 5
 
#Printing the results.#
print('Esquema(s) revelado(s):')
if v3['m1'] >= 4:
    print('Privação emocional com a media: {:.0f}'.format(v3['m1']))
    print()
    print('Questões do esquema:')
    print('01)', v3[6])
    print('19)', v3[24])
    print('37)', v3[42])
    print('55)', v3[60])
    print('73)', v3[78])
    print()
```

Now, I would like to also print the questions that got values >=4. As I said before, the name of the columns are the questions. In that way, the path would be to loc the name, get the values in the name’s row, and when they are >=4, get the column name and print it.
Like:
‘These questions also got high values (4 or above):

1. Eu não tenho ninguém que cuide de mim, que compartilhe comigo a sua vida ou que se preocupe realmente com tudo o que acontece comigo.
   04. Sou um(a) desajustado(a).”

So, my first thought was to right something like:

```
v4 = (v2.loc[nome, 6:95])
for x in v4:
  if x >= '4':
    return header
```

The problem is, I don't know how to call the header. And I don't really know if it makes sense to do it like this.
I believe that exists a simpler way to do it.

Can anyone help me with this one? =D

Answer (score 0):

Boolean indexing can be very helpful here.

```
v4 = (v2.loc[nome, 6:95])  # Select the person and the columns you want to check check
high_values = (v4 >= 4)  # Find where response was greater than or equal to 4
v5 = v4.loc[high_values]  # Take the subset of questions where condition is True
questions_with_high_values = v5.index.tolist()  # select the column header from this subset and convert it to a list.
print(questions_with_high_values)
```

This can also be boiled down into a one-liner but it's a little harder to understand what's happening.

```
questions_with_high_values = v2.columns[v2.loc[nome, 6:95] >= 4].tolist()
```

Comment: Firstt I've tried just to put the las line in the code. Got an error:

"TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

It was expected, I'm breaking my head over this all night, and got a similar result. 
.

Comment: Added (v4.astype(int) in the first code block:

v4 = (v2.loc[nome, 6:95])  # Select the person and the columns you want to check check
high_values = (v4.astype(int) >= 4)  # Find where response was greater than or equal to 4
v5 = v4.loc[high_values]  # Take the subset of questions where condition is True
questions_with_high_values = v5.index.tolist()  # select the column header from this subset and convert it to a list.
print(questions_with_high_values)

And got this:
[6, 11, 23, 41, 59, 77, 95]

 its the index, but not the columns name. I believe that the Daframe is headless.

Comment: Trying to solve this headless problem without breaking all the calculations code (because I need the index to do it) But I just dont know how.

btw, sorry about some spelling mistakes. I'm just too tired to review it right now. hehe

Comment: Interesting! We're getting closer here. It seems to me that your column names are getting converted to integers somewhere along the way or that the column names never getting loaded from your import file. 
You can check the column names by going ```print(v1.columns)```, print(v2.columns)``` etc. and seeing if they change at somepoint. But I don't see where that could be happening so I think it more likely the second option.

Comment: If you run ```print(v1.columns)``` and you get a list of integers and not strings it then the problem is with how you loading your data. I would suggest using ```pd.from_excel("<path-to-file>")``` or ```pd.from_csv("<path-to-file>")```, based on what format the file is saved as. The only problem here is that some of your downstream code won't work properly after this. For example ```v3 = (v2.loc[nome, 6:95])``` will need to be changed to ```v3 = (v2.loc[nome, :].iloc[:, 6:95])``` along with anywhere you reference a column using an integer.